# Windows 7: Route single IP over different interface (wlan)

Tags: windows, route, static-routes

I am connected via Ethernet (10.1.1.1, interface 11) as well as via Wireless LAN (172.22.12.1, interface 12). I trying to route just a certain host (140.239.191.10 - which is whatismyipaddress.com for testing purposes) via the wlan instead of the Ethernet card (which has the higher metric).

Let me give you my routing details:

```
Network Destination | Netmask         | Gateway     | Interface     | Metric
0.0.0.0             | 0.0.0.0         | 10.1.1.1    | 10.1.10.149   | 10
0.0.0.0             | 0.0.0.0         | 172.22.12.1 | 172.22.12.110 | 20
```

Now I tried the following:

```
route add 140.239.191.10 mask 255.255.255.255 172.22.12.1 metric 1 if 12
```

and I get this addition to the route table

```
140.239.191.10      | 255.255.255.255 | 172.22.12.1 | 172.22.12.110 | 31
```

And here lies the problem I think: The route is automatically assigned a metric of 31 and hence the traffic is not routed via my wlan interface, but via the ethernet (because of the lower metric). When surfing to the IP I still see the public IP address of my ethernet adapter and not the public IP address of the WLAN adapter (which are entire different networks - local DSL and UMTS).

I do not want to give the wlan the lower metric because I generally want to use the ethernet interface for all network traffic (it is faster and I can access my internal network shares) - I only want to route a single IP via the WLAN adapter.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Dennis

Comment: Windows will always use the most specific route regardless of metric (exceptions apply in certain *very uncommon* configurations). So the route you added, which is for one specific IP address will always be used for that IP regardless of it's metric (unless there is another route equally as specific, in which case metric is the arbitrator). If your browser held a persistent connection with the web server (which most HTTPv1.1 browser do) then the initial connection would have been on the LAN NIC, and would not switch to the WLAN when you added the new route.

Comment: The previous comment by @ChrisS is false. Windows 7 does not use the most specific route. See my upvote comment in my response to a downvote comment below.

Comment: @danorton What evidence or reference material do you have to back that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm - it seems to be working now without me changing anything (I actually went to get a coffee). Maybe windows takes some time to use the new settings?

Would I have to do a ipconfig /renew or something so the settings are used immediately?

Comment: I'm going to guess that if you'd tried to reach the host before adding the route, ipconfig/flushdns would get rid of the cached failure?

Comment: Yep, flushdns was the correct thing to do, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Well I am doing exactly the same and Windows 8 insists in using the "LAN" gateway... instead of the "WLAN" gateway.

So, not sure is Windows is "capricious" :) or not; but I guess this command should be straight forward to use.

Tried several combinations, like not using the specific IF for WLAN or setting a lower METRIC or using a MASK for ...108.142.0. Always the same result; it apparently gets ignored.

`route ADD 93.108.142.151 10.30.94.1 IF 13`  **(where 10.30.94.1 if the WLAN gateway)**

After the command is given a route print and a `tracert` returns

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination     Netmask          Gateway       Interface       Metric
0.0.0.0                 0.0.0.0          10.30.60.1    10.30.61.140    20
0.0.0.0                 0.0.0.0          10.30.94.1    10.30.94.25     25
93.108.142.151          255.255.255.255  10.30.94.1    10.30.94.25     21
```

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert 93.108.142.154

   1     2 ms    1 ms     1 ms  10.30.60.1
   2     1 ms    1 ms     1 ms  192.168.191.55
   3    10 ms    8 ms     8 ms  192.168.79.97
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off the Automatic Metrics of the Ethernet and WLAN connection. the automatic metrix will override the priority here.